# Why are eunuchs allowed to ride the cart to Vaes Dothrak?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In [A Game of Thrones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Game_of_Thrones) the following paragraph indicates that, on the ride to Vaes Dothrak, a cart is used to transport eunuchs, cripples, women giving birth, the very young and the very old:

> Khal Drogo had offered him a place in a cart the next day, and Viserys had accepted.
>
> In his stubborn ignorance, he had not even known he was being mocked; the carts were for **eunuchs**, cripples, women giving birth, the very young and the very old. That won him yet another name: Khal Rhaggat, the Cart King.

Why are eunuchs allowed to ride the cart?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are not  considered "men" within the full context of the word.

As you can see, the rest of the people mentioned are all weak: cripples, women giving birth, the very young and the very old. All of them are weak and most likely not able or allowed to ride a horse, therefore the Dothraki would consider eunuchs equal to cripples (which they are, in a way).

The Dothraki traditions are a little different from our own.

At Daenerys' wedding, she notes that the male Dothraki would mate with whoever, whenever and wherever they wanted. So a male Dothraki without the ability to mate, would be considered less of a man.

Just like @HorusKol said in the comments, this is a way to show how low their status is.

Comment: I understand that but they don't really have any physical incapability aside from not having any balls, literally. They can do anything the others can, such as walk.
And the dothraki aren't the most understanding people, so why would they not make them walk?

Comment: By placing the eunuchs with the women and cripples, it highlights their low status - allowing them to walk would give them some honour. By putting them on the carts, they don't even have that.

Comment: It denigrates them in the same way it denigrates Viserys.

Answer (score 1):

The general historical reason to have eunuchs around was to serve as servants or guards for ruler's consorts (harem, fraucimor).

So for them to ride on carriages makes sense as they have duties there.